# R comparison wordcloud from dataframe with quantity

Tags: r, reshape2, tm, word-cloud

I am currently struggling with the construction of a word cloud like that one : 
[image: Image from Mining Twitter with R tutorial]

To have a wordcloud like in the following image, you need a corpus of 4 texts, "ATT", "Verizon", "T-Mobile", "MetroPCS", each being a character vector. This example is from the tutorial here : [Tutorial Mining Twitter with R](https://sites.google.com/site/miningtwitter/questions/talking-about/wordclouds/comparison-cloud).

I am quite struggling because I start all from a dataframe, like this one :

```
library(wordcloud)
library(tm)

element <- c("Adams Pearmain ", "Aia Ilu ", "Airlie Red Flesh", "Akane ", "Åkerö ", "Alkmene", "Allington Pippin ", "Ambrosia ", "Anna ", "Annurca ", "Antonovka ", "Apollo ", "Ariane ", "Arkansas Black ", "Arthur Turner")
qty <- c(2, 1, 4, 3, 6, 2, 1, 4, 3, 6, 2, 1, 4, 3, 6)
category1 <- c("Red", "Green", "Red", "Green", "Yellow", "Orange", "Red", "Red", "Green", "Red", "Green", "Yellow",  "Green", "Yellow", "Orange")
category2 <- c("small", "big", "big", "small", "small", "medium", "medium", "medium", big", "big", "small", "medium", "big", "very big", "medium")
d <- data.frame(element=element, qty=qty, category1=category1, category2=category2)
```

Which gives this dataframe :

```
    element             qty category1   category2
1   Adams Pearmain      2   Red         small
2   Aia Ilu             1   Green       big
3   Airlie Red Flesh    4   Red         small
4   Akane               3   Green       big
5   Åkerö               6   Yellow      small
6   Alkmene             2   Orange      big
7   Allington Pippin    1   Red         small
8   Ambrosia            4   Red         big
9   Anna                3   Green       small
10  Annurca             6   Red         big
11  Antonovka           2   Green       small
12  Apollo              1   Yellow      big
13  Ariane              4   Green       small
14  Arkansas Black      3   Yellow      big
15  Arthur Turner       6   Orange      big
```

I would like to do a comparison wordcloud with a wordcloud of the colors (green, red, ...) given their occurrences (the qty column). In the real world example, I have small texts in a dataframe that have a count (for instance 3 = they have been expressed three times).

So here one way to do it could be to duplicate the lines as many times as the number in qty... But there I'm stuck. So far what I get is this :

```
## Subsetting two dataframes to category2 values
wordBig <- d[d$category2 == "big",]
wordSmall <- d[d$category2 == "small",]

## Extracting the vectors int he category1 columns
wordSmall <- as.vector(wordSmall$category1)
wordBig <- as.vector(wordBig$category1)

## Building the list for the corpus
wordALL <- list(wordBig, wordSmall)
```

Here the example from miningtwitter I followed wasn't working because it used `C()` instead of `list()` in order to create the element to feed to the `Corpus()` function. The result just adds under the same vector the elements and the resulting corpus has as many documents as it has elements in the list, instead of just 2 documents. **So you should use `list()` function to build comparison clouds**.

```
## Building the corpus
corpus <- Corpus(VectorSource(wordALL), readerControl = list(language = "en"))

# Cleaning
myStopWords <- c(stopwords("english"), "other", "another'")
corpus <- tm_map(corpus, removeWords, myStopWords)
corpus <- tm_map(corpus, removePunctuation)
corpus <- tm_map(corpus, removeNumbers)
```

It is better to remove punctuation after the stopwords, especially for cases in french like : `c("l'", "j'", "d'", "c'", "qu'")` where you are left with strange words like `"lesprit"` if you do not so.

```
## Matrix
tdm <- TermDocumentMatrix(corpus)
tdm <- as.matrix(tdm)

## Giving readable names
colnames(tdm) <- c("Big Size apples", "Small size apples")

## Plotting
comparison.cloud(tdm, max.words=800, scale=c(4,1), title.size=1.4)
```

So this works, basically :

[image: Wordcloud of example]

Great ! But now in my real world example I'm still stuck, for instance where I have in the dataframe :

```
    element             qty category1   category2
4   Akane               **3**   Green       big
```

It should actually be :

```
    element             qty category1   category2
4   Akane               1   Green       big
4   Akane               1   Green       big
4   Akane               1   Green       big
```

Which will dramatically change the results in my Wordclouds !!! So my question is : how to reshape my dataframe, or how to include the frequencies in the wordcloud or corpus in order to correct this result.

Comment: This is not a `dplyr` question at all.